# Unable to start Tomcat 7.0 in 45 sec in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I'm unable to start Tomcat 7.0 in 45 sec in Eclipse IDE. I have only one .jsp which says "Helloworld" under WebContent folder of dynamic web project. I have also added a [snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6eAR.jpg) .

Note: I have also tried

1. Increasing the server timeout till 300 sec.
2. Reinstalled tomcat
3. Deleted server and added again

Nothing which is mentioned in similar question seems to work.

Comment: if you will check (performance tab of task manager ) when you start your application is eating too many ram

Comment: and for me changing time to 10 minutes and then waiting for around 5 minutes it worked ;)

Comment: Even after waiting for 10 minutes i got the same error.Its a very simple helloworld project containing only one .jsp file. This is the only project which i have in my IDE.

Comment: Please tell me if there is any other way to make it work. Thanks

Comment: did you try with new build or the old one, you can also try to remove existing build from tomcat, clean it and then retry